# EmberJS generic relations

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am looking for an appropriate solution to support generic relations on my EmberJS front-end. On my backend i have a model, let's name it `Shipping`.
this model have an `adapter` field which is a generic relation to one of the adapters model. i.e. i have 3 different adapters SelfPickupAdapter, CourierAdapter, ZoneAdapter.

model #1

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('String'),
    address: DS.attr('String'),
    city: DS.attr('String')
});
```

model #2

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('String'),
    email: DS.attr('String')
});
```

model #3

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('String'),
    address: DS.attr('String'),
    zone: DS.belongTo('Zone')
});
```

And each of this adapter models should have a way to be linked to the top level model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    adapter: DS.genericRelation(['SelfPickupAdapter','CourierAdapter','ZoneAdapter']),
    order: DS.belongsTo('Order'),
});
```

Comment: Ember Data has polymorphic relationships but you would have to have your models all extend from a single base model. Is that possible in your situation?

Comment: @GJK I am not really sure what would be the implications of such extension? What is that class from which these models should extend from?

Comment: @GJK I.e. if i have just one field `name` which is set on base model class would it be enough? What about the `id` field? Should all these models share the same id tree? What if i don't have any field which is common among models can i still define a model without fields?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I'm not 100% sure how the polymorphic relationships work, I just know that Ember Data supports them, which is why I asked if that was a possibility for you.